# Is Xcode 4 required to continue iPhone development?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, backwards-compatibility

It has been a while since I've last done programming XCode for the iPhone and I have noticed that there is a new version of XCode, XCode 4, that seems to only be available for the Lion OSX according to this link https://developer.apple.com/xcode/.

I have heard from a friend that Lion has caused a lot of havoc in the app space so I was wondering if there were any compatibility issues with developing apps using an older version of Xcode.

I currently am running on Snow Leopard OSX ver 10.6.8 and am using Xcode 3.2.3. Is this setup still capable of creating fully functional applications or is an update/upgrade required?

Any and all extra information pertaining to this matter would be greatly appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to upgrade to Lion to develop with Xcode 4. Xcode 4.2 runs on Snow Leopard and is available in the link below. This release will allow you to develop for iOS up to 5.0. If you want to devlop for iOS 5.1 then you will need Xcode 4.3.2 which is only available for Lion.

https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/Developer_Tools/xcode_4.2_for_snow_leopard/xcode_4.2_for_snow_leopard.dmg

Comment: I develop applications for iOS 5 using XCode 4.2 on Snow leopard 10.6.7. Can you please conform your answer?

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know you could do that, feel free to explain how in an edit to my answer and I'll approve it.

Comment: Scratch that last comment, your right I'm thinking iOS 5.1 I'll update the answer now.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to build for iOS 5, I think you'd have to upgrade your Xcode.

Yeah, Xcode 4 is very buggy, and performance isn't as good as Xcode 3. On the other hand the development process in Xcode 4 is very very streamlined. There are so many new features that makes your development process easier. My favourite one is automatic device provisioning.